# Смена языка не работает до авторизации пользователя

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, i18n

Не работает смена языка до авторизации пользователя. Понимаю что необходимо поправить security config, но к сожалению не удалось найти решения. 
Вот конфигурация смены локализации:

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    return new CookieLocaleResolver();
}

@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    lci.setParamName("lang");
    return lci;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}
```

А это конфигурация security:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/",
                        "/registration",
                        "/static/**",
                        "/styles/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
                .formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/main", true)
            .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
}
```

Подскажите в чём проблемма.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос решился добавлением "/login" в секцию .antMatchers

```
 .antMatchers("/",
              "/registration",
              "/static/**",
              "/styles/**",
              "/login").permitAll()
```